# includegraphics with width from included file

Tags: scaling, includegraphics

I have the following problem: I would like to include some pdfs of different sizes in my document (different width, but same font size), such that they APPEAR as the same size, even though the actual sizes differ.

Some background:
I use tikz in a standalone environment to generate several decision trees (obvious reason: otherwise my main paper gets too long and difficult to read, and to improve building time). Let's call these files fig1.pdf and fig2.pdf. Since the images have different content, they may be differently large. For example, one of my standalone pdfs has measurements 116.1x80.6mm, whilst another measures 66.2x51.4mm.

When inserting the pdf, I currently use

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{fig1.pdf}
\caption{Sample 1}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{fig2.pdf}
\caption{Sample 1}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
```

This gives me roughly a similar scale of the image. (Since decision trees contain text, they should APPEAR in the same size in the paper, but not really have the same measurements).

I can, of course, always calculate the factor (0.7 and 0.35) by hand. However, I was hoping that there is an option that either allows me to calculate that factor in TeX, or another parameter instead of `width=x * \textwidth` that directly scales the original pdf to a ratio of `f` of the original size.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not make the images in the sizes they are needed and then insert then without scaling at all. That is how I normally do this. Any scaling will affect the font size and make stuff inconsistant.

Comment: You can move tikz drawing code into your main tex file, and then use tikz's `external` library to save the execution time of large tikz drawings.